# get city name from latitude,longitude in specific language from google javascript api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Imagine I have latitude and longitude in my html file. First, I want google API javascript code to get the city and country name from this latitude and longitude. I made it. What I want to accomplish is, I want to get this city and country name in the specific language. for example I have latitude: 41.23123 and longitude:45.123123
When I transfer these to city name I get tsereteli avenue. As you know this is english. I want to get it in russian text. How do I do that?

Comment: What does the code look like that gets the city and country name from the coordinates?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 1):

From google maps [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization)

> By default, the Google Maps JavaScript API uses the user's preferred
>   language setting as specified in the browser, when displaying textual
>   information

*if you want the Maps JavaScript API to ignore the browser's language setting, you can force it to display information in a particular language by adding a language parameter to the* `<script>` *tag*

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&language=ru&region=RU">
</script>
```

here `ru` is **ISO Language Codes** for `Russian`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the language parameter in the url (supposing you are using JSON get API)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var latitude = 73.59852;
        var longitude = 55.40842; 
        //Set your Language
        var language = "ru";
        var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+latitude+","+longitude+"&sensor=true&language="+language;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            success: function(data){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
    });
```

Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Localization)

Comment: Thanks Guys,I already knew that ! my question was something else ,but anyway i figured it out .